# start terminal based apps from launcher

Tags: terminal, window-manager, launcher

I'm trying to launch `neovim` from my app launcher (which is `wofi`), but the thing is when I click on it's icon, nothing happens, I'm on archlinux with `Sway` as window manager. How can I get those apps to start ?.

It happens that when I installed gnome, those apps are starting inside of `gnome-teminal`, how can change that default terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a way to change the default terminals wofi looks for, which are listed below, but there's a command line option to set the terminal explicitly. To quote wofi's man page:

```
       -t, --term=TERM
              Specifies the term to use when running a program in a terminal. 
              This overrides the default terminal run order which is kitty,
              termite, gnome-terminal, weston-terminal in that order.
```

EDIT: Looks like the above is for `run` mode. If you're using `drun` mode, this is controlled by gio: see [here](https://todo.sr.ht/%7Escoopta/wofi/73). You could always symlink another terminal program to gnome-terminal if need be.